# Git: how to add a file but not track it

Tags: git, version-control, gitignore

In our .gitignore file we have `database.php` because it's a db config file which needs to be specific to each developer's local installation. However, every time I checkout the branch I have to recreate that file. It sucks.

How do I add the file so that it doesn't disappear every time, but also isn't tracked?

Comment: Could you replace `database.php` with a set of environment variables? Then each developer just has to set up their environment and you can sidestep the problem.

Comment: @mu this is precisely what we are trying to avoid. We have a lot of branches and it hurts productivity to have to reconfigure the environment every time.

Comment: Please don't do this! An optional, documented, instance-specific, unrevisioned `database-local.php` settings file is what you want to expose to the devs.

Answer (score 12):

**[Edit]** 
The duplicate identified contains a more robust solution (`git submodules`) to this question. This answer is valid, but after further consideration it is not appropriate if you want a team to get the same behaviour in each clone.
**[End Edit]**

Git supports this with the `--assume-unchanged` option for `git update-index`. This will let you commit the production version of database.php, and have developers update local versions of this file to point to their local resources.

```
git add database.php
git commit
git push
git update-index --assume-unchanged database.php
```

When/if you need to make changes to the production version of database.php:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged database.php
git commit -a
git update-index --assume-unchanged database.php
```

Also each developer will need to run `git update-index --assume-unchanged database.php` if the want this too as this command only affects the local repository.

You will want to ensure by some other mechanism that `database.php` fails for developers fails on non-production machines - don't want developers pointing to production obviously :)

Note you will need to remove the database.php file from your ignore list before you can add it.

Comment: Here's what I get when I try to `git add database.php`: fatal: pathspec 'database.php' did not match any files. I think it's because it's currently in .gitignore. Do I need to remove it from gitignore first?

Comment: @mounds - you missed one key and essential portion of this answer. `git push` will **NOT** and **CANNOT** push your changes to the index (for `--assume-unchanged`) since it is not an actual change that can be propagated to the remote. The option only sets the `assume-unchanged` bit for the working tree's file path in the local repo. Hence each developer needs to run this command in his local repo (after every new clone), to ensure changes to `database.php` do not get tracked.

Comment: Thanks @Tuxdude, good point, I've have edited my answer to clarify this.

Answer (score 6):

It is a really bad idea to add a file to a repository under version control and then asking git not to track any changes to the file. Files which are added under version control are meant to be versioned and tracked, and if you do not want to track any changes to a file, the rule of the thumb is **DO NOT** add it in the first place.

Agreed that people have their own preferences, and git supports these workflows to some extent as well, but you would rarely see people using it, and would favor much cleaner and straight-forward solutions instead. In fact the use case which the OP is requesting (adding a file under version control and make git to stop tracking any changes to the file, and make this possible for all future clones/fetches/pulls), is not directly feasible in `git` at all.

`.gitignore` is used for excluding files from accidentally going under version control and also for git not listing any changes to it in commands like `git status`. But if a file already exists under version control, git does not care if that file is part of `.gitignore` and starts tracking changes to it.

Instead I would recommend that you add a template file called `database-template.php` and make every user create a copy of it as `database.php` and input his/her changes into it. You could also probably write a simple script which does that.

Along with that, add `database.php` to your `.gitignore` and you're good to go, so that the user's local copy does not get into version  control.

**Alternative Solution**:
There is another way to do this, but each developer should do it his local repo, and this is really a bad approach IMO:

```
# Ask git to stop tracking any changes to database.php
git update-index --assume-unchanged database.php

# If you want to start tracking changes again to database.php
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged database.php
```

Comment: Why is it a really bad idea?

Comment: I'm also confused why that is so terrible. I thought this was the exact reason for gitihnore

Comment: @Emerson, exact reason for `.gitignore` is to ignore automatically-generated gibberish which might be easily recreated (like object files and binaries produced by a compiler, logs, text editor swap and backup files etc).  Such files get in the way when you do `git status` or `git add .`, so that's why `.gitignore` exists.

Comment: @Emerson `.gitignore` is for ignoring files which are not and should not go under version control. Once a file is under version control, git would track its changes even it is part of the `.gitignore`.

Comment: @mounds - why I mentioned it is a bad idea, is it is not seamlessly possible to do this with `git`.